# How to Give images Dynamically using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my coding's i gave images like this ,

```js
   <h3>Posted Tasks</h3>
<input type="text" class="search" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search Job Posts Here" style="width: 314px;padding-bottom: 14px;"/>
<p> Hello "User" , These are all the works posted by the users. Select those tasks according to Your Category .</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div  ui-sref="jobPostSearch" class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="x in tasklist|filter:searchString">
<div class="main-box clearfix profile-box">
  <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
 <div class="profile-box-header" style="background-image: url(app/utils/poo2.jpg);padding-bottom:222px;">
 
   <div style=""></div>
 </div>
        <div class="profile-box-footer clearfix" >
   <span class="value" >  {{x.jobTitle}}</span>
   <span>{{x.jobDescription}}</span>
```

But i need to give images dynamically, referred in many sites but didn't get the clear idea, can someone help me out plz !

Comment: dynamic images with angular can be done with [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: Well, was referred that site already. But don't know how to implement that code into my Pgm. (Am newbie, thats why this much of Struggling ) !!

Comment: my fault, i didn't notice the *background* image part of this

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below example

```
<div class="modalContainerClass" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')'}">
```

Comment: Nikita , Thanks ..will try that now.

Comment: Can yu pls Explain me this Line : *** 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')' ***  what exactly it will do ?

Comment: selectedMeal.url, has all the url's, anular will parse this variable.
You can use your own variable in place.